# Disallow User to Enter Text in Autocomplete Input Box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

All,

I am trying to assign a value from a Razor variable to a property (error:) in some JS.

I am getting a syntax error in VS2012 on the comma, immediately following my Razor variable. Probably need some sort of delimeter so Razor knows how to deal with the text following the variable?

How can I do this? Should be simple enough. Thanks

```
@model MyProject.Models.ViewModels.Shared.NotificationAlertViewModel
@{
    string isError = (Model.IsErrorMessage ? "true" : "false");
 } 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#loading-area').hide();

    $.notification({
      content: @Model.Message,
      error: @isError,
      timeout: 5000
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't know what `@isError` means or how to access it. Use...

```
$.notification({
  content: @Model.Message,
  error: '@isError',
  timeout: 5000
});
```

The quotes tell Razor to return the value of the variable in a way JS can understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
set value in ViewBag and use it.

```
@model MyProject.Models.ViewModels.Shared.NotificationAlertViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
 var @isError='@(ViewBag.IsErrorMessage)';
    $('#loading-area').hide();

    $.notification({
      content: @Model.Message,
      error: @isError,
      timeout: 5000
    });

</script>
```